# Page awareness to be able to assign classes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

So I have a list of users within a list of taxonomies in a sidebar.  I need to be able to have the list of users stay open (they are closed by default and open on click) if the current page is a user page.  So for a user within taxonomy A, on that users page the list of users for taxonomy A would be open by default.  Basically, I need to create a context awareness similar to how WordPress does with menus.

Here is the loop that creates the list:

```
<div class="sidebar sidebar-people">
  <div class="menu-people-menu-container">
    <?php $disciplines = get_terms('disciplines');
  echo "<ul id='menu-people-menu' class='menu'>";
  foreach($disciplines as $discipline) {
    $params = array('limit' => -1,'where' => 'user_discipline.term_id = ' . (int) $discipline->term_id. ''); 
    $mypod = pods( 'user', $params );
    if ( 0 < $mypod->total() ) { 
    echo '<li><a href="#">' . $discipline->name . '</a>';

      $users = get_users('meta_value='. $discipline->term_id .'');
      if(count($users)>0) { 
        echo '<ul class="sub-menu postid-'. get_the_id() .'">';
        foreach( $users as $user ){
          echo '<li><a href="'. home_url(mb_strtolower('/culture/our-people/'. $user->user_firstname .'-'. $user->user_lastname) ). '">' . $user->user_firstname .' '. $user->user_lastname . '</a></li>';
        }
      } else {
        echo '<li><a href="#">No results found</a></li>';
      }

        echo '</ul></a></li>';
    }
  }

  echo "</ul>";

  ?>  

  </div> 
</div>
```

And here's the JS that opens and closes it:

```
//Sidebar Menu SLide Toggles
$("#menu-people-menu").on("click", "> li > a", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#menu-people-menu").find(".sub-menu").hide();
    $(this).closest("li").find(".sub-menu").first().fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

How do I go about keeping taxonomy a open when on the user 1 page dynamically?

Taxonomy A
-user 1
-user 2
-user 3
Taxonomy B
-user 4
-user 5
-user 6
Taxonomy C
-user 7
-user 8
-user 9

Comment: Sorry, question edited.

Comment: Are you looking to base the logic on being on a specific page or based on a specific user looking at the page?